# Jquery UI position plugin is not working with margin property

Tags: jquery, html, css, position

I am trying to position a box on the top right screen of my browser using the jquery ui position plugin as,

```
$('.container').position({
    my : 'right top',
    at : 'right top',
    of : 'body'
});
```

This works properly and is getting displayed on the top right. But i like to give some space between the box and the right side screen edge. So, i added `margin-right` position to the container. Immediately, the box moved from the top right corner to left corner.

Plunker code is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/DE8dAPxxX61JvEtnhVO7?p=preview).

Why does margin property affect the container's absolute coordinates?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here but if you're trying to position `.container` why wouldn't you use `CSS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the margin to the container will cause jquery-ui to wrongly calculate the position of the element, however you have the ability to do so using the position function itself:

```
at : 'right-10px top'
```

Besides that, in order to make sure jquery will position the element in the right place, the content should be inside the element before positioning.

In this example you have 2 buttons. The first button will position a box in the right corner, while the second button will position a box in the right corner-10px.

```js
$('.myButton1').click(function(){
 console.log('adding new element into the div container')
 $('.container1').append('<div class="noti-msg">this is a long small notification message... this width will fall down to the next level</div>');
  $('.container1').position({
 my : 'right top',
 at : 'right top',
 of : 'body'
}); 
});
$('.myButton2').click(function(){
 console.log('adding new element into the div container')
 $('.container2').append('<div class="noti-msg">this is a long small notification message... this width will fall down to the next level</div>');
  $('.container2').position({
 my : 'right top',
 at : 'right-10px top',
 of : 'body'
}); 
});
```

```css
.container1, .container2 {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.container2 {
  background: red;
}
.noti-msg{
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.css' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js'></script>
<button class="myButton1">my button 1...</button>
<button class="myButton2">my button 2...</button>
<br/>
<div class="container1">
</div>
<div class="container2">
</div>
```